# VBox auto resize gone after kernel upgrade

Tags: debian

I recently installed Debian in a Virtual Box, I had it working good until I upgraded the kernel, now my screen size is fixed and don't know what happened

Answer (score 2):

Re-installing the linux headers solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

inserted the virtual disc for Vbox Guest additions

```
sudo cp /media/cdrom0/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /tmp/
sudo /tmp/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Auto resize guest display no longer grayed out.